# Simplifying inversion

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-equations, random-matrices

**Issue:** I have two random column vectors $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^L$ and would like to simplify the following expression:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{E}[aa^\top] & \mathbb{E}[bb^\top]
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{E}[aa^\top] & \mathbb{E}[ab^\top] \\
\mathbb{E}[ba^\top] & \mathbb{E}[bb^\top]
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.
$$

Simplify here means I would like to rewrite the matrix such that I do as little inversion as possible and also invert as small a matrix as possible.

**Attempt:** I tried using all the various block matrix inversion [formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion), but I couldn't simplify the expression after substituting the various formulas. Is there another way or is this as simple as we can go? Thanks.